# Is there a C++ equivalent to Python's 'fromfile'?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I am rewriting someone's code from Python to C++ so that I can do some more fine-grained optimization.

The code I am working with uses `fromfile` from `scipy` to read binary files, though the person I am working with does not know the structure of these binary files. I am used to reading `ASCII` files with `C`/`C++` and am unsure how to read data of an unknown binary format using `C++`. I'm assuming this must be possible since the `fromfile` function allows a binary file as input and returns the contents.

Is there a `C++` equivalent to this function and / or could someone point me in the right direction on how to read contents of an arbitrary binary file using `C++`?

Comment: You can use the `std::ifstream::read()` function to read binary data.

Comment: @AmiTavory Nope, the OP wants to read binary data.

Comment: As @πάνταῥεῖ pointed out, `std::ifstream::read()` is the way to go here. You would get a pointer to char, which could be iterated and treated as an array of bytes.

Comment: You'll get better performance with good old-fashioned `fread()`.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst: 1) Sources. 2) Implementation-dependent. 3) C-style file handles don't close themselves when going out of scope (e.g. when an exception is thrown). I find it dubious advice to point someone toward C I/O functions in a C++ question.